# Change namespace of a node

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-namespaces

I load with ajax this xml with MathML element:

```
<div><math>......</math></div>
```

then before insert the node to document, apply this preprocessing with javascript:

```
var list = xml.getElementsByTagName(element);
for (var z = 0; z < list.length; z++) list[z].setAttribute('xmlns', xmlns);
```

where element='math' and xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'

Code output is correct, but MathML is not rendering.

How can I fix it?

If AJAX loading xml is:

```
<div><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">......</math></div>
```

it works fine.
But I don't want all these dirty xmlns in my text.

Comment: You need the MathML xmlns to render it as MathML!

Comment: Yes @Praveen Kumar. So that is the reason to add it with javascript. The question is why adding xmlns with javascript is not working.

Comment: Oh okay... Not sure though!